# crypto confirmation using django

Tags: python, django, payment, cryptocurrency

hey im creating a website where users need to send thir crypto namely usdt or worldcoin, im having trouble knowing who and what amount has been sent so that i can realise products, please help

this is me trying to fetch prices using api

```
sync def home(request):
    # Fetch Worldcoin (WLD) and USD prices from CoinGecko API asynchronously
    wld_price, usd_price = await asyncio.gather(fetch_price('worldcoin'), fetch_price('usd'))

    return render(request, 'index.html', {'wld_price': wld_price, 'usd_price': usd_price})

async def fetch_price(currency):
    api_url = f'https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids={currency}&vs_currencies=usd&x_cg_demo_api_key=CG-vQnfgGR63qMZ2LVVJfLJ2Wj2'
    response = await asyncio.to_thread(lambda: requests.get(api_url))
    data = response.json()
    return data[currency]['usd']
```